# reverse with view function not working with multiple urls.py files

Tags: python, django

I'm having issues with using the `reverse()` function with a view-function as argument. It work's fine when I specify the URL routing in the default `urls.py` file. But when I have a `import` to a secondary `urls.py` file I get `NoReverseMatch`-errors.

So... This is how my urls.py files looks like.

*demostore/demostore/urls.py*

```
#demostore/demostore/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('lindshop.urls', namespace="shop")),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

*demostore/lindshop/urls.py*:

```
#demostore/lindshop/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.landing, name='index'), 
    ...
    url(r'^product-index/$', 'lindshop.core.product.views.product_index', name="product_index"), 
]
```

My `product_index` view is just an empty view without any arguments that looks like this:

```
def product_index(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, "index.html")
```

Now... When I call

```
reverse('lindshop.core.product.views.product_index')
```

I get a `NoReverseMatch` error. HOWEVER, if I put my `url(r'^product-index/$'...)` in the *demostore/demostore.urls.py*, the `reverse()` works fine. But this is not what I'm looking for, I want to keep all URL-routing in my custom app's `urls.py`.

Comment: Don't try. Use the explicit name. Using a string view path in urls is deprecated, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added a namespace, so you need to resolve the urls correctly (refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) for more details):

```
reverse('shop:product_index')
```

---

> Obviously I don't want to use Namespace in this case. If you read my
>   question I want to call it by function name, which IS working when I
>   put the routing in the demostore/demostore/urls.py file. But not in
>   the included lindshop/urls.py file. And yes... it does work with
>   reverse('shop:product_index'). But that's not what I want.

If you read the [documentation for `reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse), you'll find this snippet:

> Deprecated since version 1.8:
>
> The ability to reverse using the Python path, e.g.
>   reverse('news.views.archive'), has been deprecated.

Comment: reverse('lindshop:product_index')  think app name is lindshop.

Comment: Obviously I don't want to use Namespace in this case. If you read my question I want to call it by function name, which IS working when I put the routing in the demostore/demostore/urls.py file. But not in the included lindshop/urls.py file.

And yes... it does work with `reverse('shop:product_index')`. But that's not what I want.